# Не работает цикл, перебирающий список сессий

Tags: java, spring, сессия, foreach

```
ArrayList<Product> cartCount = new ArrayList<>();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Product product = (Product) session.getAttribute("cart");
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

        HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
        Product product1 = (Product) session1.getAttribute("cart1");
        session1.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

        if (product == null && product1 == null) {
            product = new Product(name, price, item_size, quantity, img, color);
            session.setAttribute("cart", product);
            cartCount.add(product);
            System.out.println("Товар1 в корзине");
        } else if (product1 == null) {
            product1 = new Product(name, price, item_size, quantity, img, color);
            //здесь остановка программы
            for (Product s : cartCount) {
                if (!product1.equals(s)) {
                    session1.setAttribute("cart1", product1);
                    cartCount.add(product1);
                    System.out.println("Товар2 в корзине");
                }
            }
        }
        return "redirect:/basket";
    }
```

Не добавляется атрибут сессии в цикле foreach.
В чем может быть причина? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Product представляет из себя сущность БД с `get` и `set` методами

Comment: "не работает" не является описанием проблемы

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать *желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: что не работает в вашем коде?

Comment: @Зонтик добавил пояснение. Цикл foreach не выполняется

Comment: @andreydragunov Напишите, пожалуйста,  какой результат вы ожидаете получить от программы, какая ошибка у вас появляется. Чем больше информации вы нам предоставите, тем быстрее мы сможем вам помочь с вашей проблемой.

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn я пишу корзину интернет-магазина. Мне нужно устанавливать атрибут сессии после проверки на уникальность (цикл должен перебирать все сессии и сравнивать)

Comment: @andreydragunov Хорошо, а какая конкретная ошибка возникла?

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn, ошибки как таковой не возникло, но код внутри цикла почему-то не работает. Ломаю голову из-за чего это может быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас создан **пустой список `cartCount`**, в который *ничего не было добавлено*, и после проверки условия `if (product1 == null)` создаётся и присваивается переменная `product1`.  Итерация по пустому списку сразу же завершается.

Скорее всего у вас *подразумевается*, что в списке каким-то образом должен оказаться товар `product`, но возникает сомнение, что этот локальный список так уж необходим.  Также непонятно, зачем создаётся синоним для сессии `session1`, вполне хватило бы одной переменной.

Вариант исправленного кода:

```java
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Product product  = (Product) session.getAttribute("cart");
Product product1 = (Product) session.getAttribute("cart1");
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

if (product == null && product1 == null) { 
    // оба товара отсутствуют, создаётся первый
    product = new Product(name, price, item_size, quantity, img, color);
    session.setAttribute("cart", product);
    System.out.println("Товар1 в корзине");
} else if (product1 == null) {
    // в корзине есть первый товар, отсутствует только второй товар
    product1 = new Product(name, price, item_size, quantity, img, color); 
    if (!product1.equals(product)) {
        // добавили в корзину второй товар, если он отличается от первого
        session.setAttribute("cart1", product1);
        System.out.println("Товар2 в корзине");
    }
}
return "redirect:/basket";
```

---

Если нужно обеспечить уникальность товаров, можно использовать `Set` вместо `List`, в частности метод `Set:add` возвращает `true`, если множество было изменено, то есть при обнаружении дубликата будет возвращаться `false`:

```java
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

Set<Product> cart = new LinkedHashSet<>();
List<String> attribs = Arrays.asList("cart", "cart1", "cart2"); // и т.д.

for (String attr : attribs) {
    Product product = (Product) session.getAttribute(attr);
    if (null == product) {
        product = new Product(name, price, item_size, quantity, img, color);
    }
    if (cart.add(product)) { // товар успешно добавлен, нет дубликата
        session.setAttribute(attr, product);
        System.out.println("Товар " + product.getName() + " в корзине");
    }    
}

return "redirect:/basket";
```

Comment: До этого, у меня было такое же сравнение. Но мне нужна проверка на уникальность в сравнении со **всеми** объектами, которых может быть больше 20 в корзине. Метод equals даёт возможность сравнения только двух элементов. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Откуда у вас будут браться _другие_ товары?  Вы сохраняете в сессии их список?

Comment: Я создаю новый объект сессии вручную: product1,2,3... И у меня возникает проблема с проверкой на уникальность

Comment: Может проще будет использовать сет, а не список?  Он гарантированно будет содержать уникальные товары.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет! Буду использовать сеты. Если только один параметр в объекте product будет различен от других, то объекты будут уникальными в сетах, так?

Comment: Это зависит от того, как у вас будут переопределены методы `hashCode` / `equals` в классе `Product`.  Если проверка равенства / вычисление хэш-кода экземпляра учитывают все поля, тогда любое изменение будет приводить к уникальности.

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, и приведите пример.  Учтите, что нужно также переопределить `hashCode`